# Netcat with named pipe

Tags: networking, pipe, named-pipes, netcat

I have a client that connects to a server on `localhost:10000`.  The server is not in the same host. But we can not access to the server from IP network. For this we are writing our own network driver that will create a virtual network interface. Then `10000` on that server will be available.

For now, we are trying write an application that just mimics the server behavior. It should listen to `localhost:10000` and writes any incoming data to a named pipe. Also write any incoming data on named pipe to the connected clients.  I believe this can be done very easily using a simple tool called `netcat` or `nc`.  How do I do that?

I have this [fifo](/questions/tagged/fifo) named `fifo`. I execute

```
nc -l 4444 > ../fifo
```

This command only writes any data found on incoming connection to the fifo. How do I make it two way? meaning it should both read from and write into the pipe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This can be done using two FIFOs**. Suppose they are `in` and `out`.

You run your netcat server as

```
nc -l 4444 < in > out
```

#### How this work

`nc -l 4444` listens to local `4444` port for any incoming connection. When connected it sends any thing found on `in` pipe to the client and writes anything from the client to `out` fifo.

Comment: This is not working the port does not listen as it blocks waiting for something at `in`.

Comment: I know it blocks. But for a single transaction it works.

Comment: No transaction worked for me. It blocked! It's not even listening, when i tested.